# Update one-to-many relation in EF with only the ForeingKey Id

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I have a database relation that consists of this:

```
public class Study {
    public int StudyId { get; set; }

    public int? PatientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Study> Hospitals { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say that I want to update a study with a new patient, but that patient is inside the database.

What I try to do is to query for the id of that patient (let's say it's 3) and set the `study.PatientId` to `3` and `study.Patient` to `null`.

Running a `AddOrUpdate` in that study, will return in the ForeignKey from `Study` to `Patient` being `null` instead of `3`.

Does that mean that if I want to update the `Study` with that `Patient`, then I need to query to the whole `Patient` object from the database instead of only it's Id and then set the `study.PatientId` to `3` and `study.Patient` to the queried `Patient` object?

if so, is there some other way to be able to do that with only the `PatientId` instead of the whole object queried?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of this, but have you tried only setting the PatientId and leaving the Patient field alone?

Comment: To update study no need of patient object or patient id because patient id is nullable. Or if you want to map study with patient id 3 then you can update study with patient id 3 no need of patient object if patient id 3 is not exist in database then ef6 will throw exception

Comment: Please post your query code as well, this will improve your question and make it more answerable. It's important to determine exactly what you're doing to query and update your objects.